# How does `lapply()` handle adding elements to a list?

Tags: r, list, lapply

Consider the following code.

```
set.seed(1)
my_list <- c()
for (i in seq(4L)){
  n <- sample(1:10L, 1L)
  v <- list(sample(seq(n), replace=TRUE))
  my_list <- append(my_list, v)
}
str(my_list)
# List of 4
#  $ : int [1:9] 4 7 1 2 7 2 3 1 5
#  $ : int [1:5] 2 2 1 5 5
#  $ : int [1:9] 9 5 5 2 9 1 4 3 6
#  $ : int [1:10] 10 6 4 4 10 9 7 6 9 8

## `stats_for' is a list containing the sum statistics collected from `my_list`.
my_fun <- function(x) { stats <- sum(x) }

stats_for <- list()            
for (i in seq_along(my_list)){
  stats_for <- append(stats_for, my_fun(my_list[[i]]))
}

## above for-loop can be replaced by.
## stats_lap <- lapply(my_list, function(x) { stats <- sum(x) } )
stats_lap <- lapply(my_list, sum ) # Courtesy of Rui
identical(stats_lap, stats_for)
```

In the context of the `lapply()` function:

- stats is initialized to empty.
- sum(x) is appended.

I have come across this behavior by trial and error.

My question: is this behaviour of `lapply` documented anywhere?

Comment: 1) `stats_lap <- lapply(my_list, my_fun)` is simpler; 2) yes, this is documented, the (anonymous) function `lapply` calls is like any other function and a list is created with the *function's return values*. This list is the return value of `lapply`, it does not append to a list, it creates a new one from scratch.

Comment: @Rui Barradas, I missed that. If you change this comment in an answer I can accept it.

In my original code the for-loop, including my_fun, is not present. The anonymous function is fine.